# Changing OS X keyboard shortcuts to match Windows for copy/paste AND switching between open apps

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to modify my Mac OS X keyboard such that <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> continues to be the way to switch between open applications, but also such that <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut to copy. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's far, far easier to just learn the difference. Cmd/Win and opt/alt are in different positions too, so you just get used to it after a while. [Speaking as someone who's been using Macs for 30 years & Windows for 20]

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to, in Modifier Keys in Keyboard settings, set both the <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd> keys to be the <kbd>command</kbd> key.